# C# VisualStudio HttpListenerContext Unit tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, юнит-тесты

```
[TestMethod()]
        public void IsServerExistTest()
        {
            init();
            ServerAdd serverAdd = new ServerAdd(listenerContext);
            Assert.AreEqual(serverAdd.IsServerExist("62.210.26.88-1337"),1);
        }
```

пишу проект на C#. Создал тест выше. Он использует HttpListenerContext. Как я могу сделать так, чтобы получать HttpListenerContext и проводить тестирование?

Comment: Что-то не совсем понял, Вы уже используете `HttpListenerContext` и спрашиваете *как получать HttpListenerContext*? Здесь явно что-то не уточнено.

Comment: Это тест. Я хочу в него подать объект HttpListenerContext. Но этот объект надо где-то взять. При обычном запуске, не тестировании, я отправляю запросы, а при тестировании я хочу эти запросы симулировать. И должен создать HttpListenerContext. Как это сделать? @DenisBubnov

Comment: Аааа... понял Вас. Гляньте вот этот ответ про моки: [Mocking HttpListenerContext](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15092080/5275890)

Comment: @DenisBubnov Можете пояснить про то что там происходит? Я не понимаю. Мы создаем абстрактный класс, а дальше непонятно. Что такое HttpListenerRequestBase и т.д?

Comment: Создать этот абстрактный класс, затем создать класс-оболочку, который принимает `HTTPListnerContext` в конструкторе и наследует `HttpListenerContextBase`. После этого, этот класс-оболочка будет возвращает методы из реального контекста, только нужно будет заполнить методы `HttpListenerContextBase`. Это своего рода оболочка. Нет проекта под рукой, где бы я мог воспроизвести пример... :(

Comment: @DenisBubnov Вроде понятно. Только что значит заполнять HttpListenerContextBase? Каким образом?

Comment: Заполнить `Request`, `Response` и `User`, к примеру в конструкторе Вашей оболочки.

Comment: @DenisBubnov Я понимаю что нужно заполнить:) Я не понимаю как именно. Ну т.е я должен HttpListenerRequest присвоить как-то значение. А какое оно? И как его сформировать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обёртка о которой говорится в комментариях:

```
public abstract class HttpListenerContextBase
    {
        public virtual HttpListenerRequest Request { get; protected set; }
        public virtual HttpListenerResponse Response { get; protected set; }
        public virtual IPrincipal User { get; protected set; }
    }
```

Для того, чтобы использовать обёртку, о которой говорится в комментариях, вам необходимо модифицировать класс ServerAdd.
Грубо говоря, если было так:

```
public class Server
{
    private HttpListenerContext context;

    public Server(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String AwaitRequest()
    {
        return $"Got http {context.Request.HttpMethod} request with url {context.Request.RawUrl}";
    }
}
```

То должно стать примерно так:

```
public class TestableServer
{
    private HttpListenerContextBase context;

    public TestableServer(HttpListenerContextBase context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String AwaitRequest()
    {
        return $"Got http {context.Request.HttpMethod} request with url {context.Request.RawUrl}";
    }
}
```

Соответственно, обёртка выглядит следующим образом (код, который используется в реальной системе - не в тестах):

```
public class HttpListenerContextWrapperReal : HttpListenerContextBase
{
    public HttpListenerContextWrapperReal(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        this.Request = context.Request;
        this.Response = context.Response;
        this.User = context.User;
    }
}
```

Использование класса TestableServer:

```
var server = new TestableServer(new HttpListenerContextWrapperReal(context));
var request = server.AwaitRequest();
```

Вместо вашего варианта:

```
var server = new Server(context);
var request = server.AwaitRequest();
```

Позволит вам создать класс, наподобие HttpListenerContextWrapperMock (унаследованный от HttpListenerContextBase), в котором перегруженные методы будут возвращать не реальные значения, а те, которые вы определите в вашем моке.
Так, в своём тесте вы сможете использовать что-то вроде:

```
var server = new TestableServer(new HttpListenerContextWrapperMock());
var request = server.AwaitRequest();
```

PS: Учитывая, что конкретная реализация HttpListenerContextBase передаётся в качестве аргумента конструктора, в такой ситуации полезно будет использовать IoC-контейнер.

PPS: Классы HttpListenerRequest и HttpListenerResponse также запечатаны (sealed), поэтому посмотрите в сторону Moq и других подобных фреймворков. Думаю, смысл понятен.

Comment: Хорошее объяснение. Спасибо большое